# So which database to choose that is free for massive web site?

Tags: database

Now that Oracle own MySQL and I'm not sure about the licensing.

What options do I have for free database?

Comment: Even though now owned by Oracle, MySQL is still provided under the GPL (as it always has been), so it's still free.

Comment: More information on what you intend to do with the database will help you get useful answers. And +1 to Josh3736, MySQL is still GPL, there are also a number of fork projects of it.

Answer (score 4):

If it's relational you want, perhaps [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) is your answer.

[NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org/) offers several non-relational alternatives, depending on your requirements.

But if MySQL really is your cup of tea you should get someone to dig deeper into licensing for you and see if you can have peace of mind and keep MySQL. "I'm not sure" seems to be a poor reason to cast aside an investment in technology that you know well.  Oracle's had MySQL for a while now.  I'd recommend looking into it to figure it out one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

there are too many DATABASES are available for free to use.

```
PostgreSQL
MySQL
BerkeleyDB
Firebird (database server) Etc..
```

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL and BDB are owned by Oracle and the OP is wary of that.

Answer (score 0):

[MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) is almost a [drop-in replacement](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) for MySQL.